# Is it possible to use Alea GPU on Linux with .NET Core?

Tags: c#, .net-core, gpu, aleagpu

Is it possible to use **Alea GPU** on Linux by targeting **.NET Core**?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Currently, it is not supported, but you may get some simpler use cases working. A first .NET core release of Alea GPU is expected by November/December.

Comment: Any update on this? Alea has the best API in my opinion. I think it would be a big selling point to have .NET Core support.

Comment: Alea GPU on .NET core is available as an enterprise solution only.

Comment: Oh ok. I didn't see it anywhere on the Alea site.

Comment: @Daniel Alea GPU appears to be a dead project. Do you know of any similar alternatives?

Comment: @Tim No it is not a dead project, you can always buy the enterprise addition.

Comment: The examples don't build, and the website is full of dead links though?

Comment: @Tim did you use these examples: http://www.aleagpu.com/release/3_0_4/doc/gallery.html ?

Comment: I clicked on one of the example tiles from that page and downloaded AleaSample.CS.ParallelFor.zip. I should have been more precise though, it builds, it just doesn't run due to an exception "Could not load file or assembly 'FSharp.Core, Version=4.4.0.0". 4.4 isn't available from nuget anymore and  4.7.2 won't work even though automatic binding redirects is turned on. Also, I see the Alea nuget packages have not been updated since 2017